# How do you compare two fields using Wixel/GUMP validation class

Tags: php, validation

I know how to compare the password and the confirm password field for validation but recently I updated to [GUMP php validation](https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP) library. If you have used it, you know about the ease of using it, plus it is much better than coming up with your own validation code.

That said, I do not see how you compare password and the confirm password field. If you can help me comparing these two (password and confirm password) I'd be grateful.

If you want to see what I was doing

```
$customer_name = $_POST['your_name'];
$customer_email = $_POST['your_email'];
$customer_mobile_number = $_POST['mobile_number'];
$customer_password = $_POST['password'];
$password_confirmation = $_POST['password_confirmation'];

$_POST = array( 'name' => $customer_name,
                       'email' => $customer_email,
                       'mobilenumber' => $customer_mobile_number,
                       'password' => $customer_password,
                       'confirmpassword' => $password_confirmation
);

$rules = array('name' => 'required|alpha_space|max_len,120|min_len,3',
                    'email' => 'required|valid_email|max_len,120|min_len,7',
                    'mobilenumber' => 'required|phone_number|exact_len,10',
                    'password' => 'required|max_len,15|min_len,6'
);

$filters = array('name' => 'trim|sanitize_string',
                    'email' => 'trim|sanitize_email',
                    'mobilenumber' => 'trim|sanitize_numbers',
                    'password' => 'trim|sha1'
);
```

Comment: I presume you'd need to do this outside of GUMP with some basic if $customer_password == $password_confirmation. According to their TODO, a password validation is coming (https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP#todo)

Comment: @AdamA, that will be my last resort Adam.

Comment: @AdamA, my bad... I did not go through their Todo.